# Javascript failing to parse JSON when chrome console parses perfectly

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

I have come a bit stuck when essentially trying to return some coordinates from a database for google maps API to produce a polygon.

I first grab my data from the database using Laravel Framework :

MapController -

```
public function getallmapcoords(request $request)
{
    $pd = ParishData::limit(10)->get();
    return json_encode($pd);
}
```

I then parse all the data and narrow it down to just the coordinates what I want.

Ajax -

```
  $.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: '{{route("getallmapcoords")}}',
beforeSend:function(){
$('.loader').append('<div id="progress"><img src="{{asset("img/wheel.gif")}}"><br><span class="loadertext">Loading...</span></div>');
  $('#progress').center(); //call the center function, centres the progress div in the
},
success:function(data){
  $('.loader').empty();

  parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
  coords = parsedData[0]['coordinates'];
  console.log(coords);
  parsedcoords = JSON.parse(coords);
  console.log(parsedcoords);

},
error:function(){
  // failed request; give feedback to user
},
complete:function(data){
  $('.loader').empty();
}
});
```

The first console.log displays out the coordinates as a string as shown :

[image]

The second console.log produces the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 4
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (<anonymous>:170:27)
at fire (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:83), <anonymous>:3268:31)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:83), <anonymous>:3398:7)
at done (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:83), <anonymous>:9305:14)
at XMLHttpRequest.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:83), <anonymous>:9548:9)
```

Upon copying the first console.log (string version) into google chrome console and assigned a variable, it returns a object, which is the format I want.

[image]

The bit that confuses me is why Google chrome parses it fine but JSON.Parse fails?

An example of the string I am returning :

https://pastebin.com/c9rq9HqE

Thank you for any help you may provide and if there is a better way of doing this on the PHP side too I am all ears!

Comment: *"The first console.log displays out the coordinates as a string as shown"* No, it shows an *array*, not a string. No need to parse it again. You already did that. (You shouldn't have to parse it yourself even once, much less twice; if the PHP response correctly sends `application/json` as the content type, or you include `dataType: "json"` in the `ajax` call, jQuery will parse it for you.)

Comment: The coordinate data is stored within the first json as a string. I then access the coordinates with coords = parsedData[0]['coordinates']; which has a TypeOf String I then parse it again to convert that string into a JSON.

Comment: Show the actual JSON text returned at the network layer. I suspect you'll find that the coordinates are *not* buried in a double-encoded string. And if they are, that's the problem you should fix; it makes no sense to encode JSON as JSON.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? Once initial string is parsed for the first time it is in this format: https://gyazo.com/dfdd00038a3a9881214fb91833054101
Thats just the database data in a object format.

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing the object twice:

```
parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
coords = parsedData[0]['coordinates'];
console.log(coords);
parsedcoords = JSON.parse(coords);
console.log(parsedcoords);
```

should be:

```
parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
coords = parsedData[0]['coordinates'];
console.log(coords);
```

Comment: The coordinates are stored within the first object as a string so I need to parse a second time to get that data into an object format.